# CSS3 columns cutting off <li>s

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am trying to use css3 columns with a list (`<li>`).
I am having trouble making it work.

I defined a div that wraps the `<ul>`

```
div.ul-container {
  -moz-column-width: 310px;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-width: 310px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-width: 310px;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

This works fine when I have three `<li>`s or above. But when I have less than that (2 or 1) it seems to cut off the `<li>`. I tried defining a `min-height` which didn't work as well (it treated it as height).

screenshot:

[image: cutting off li]

any ideas?

Comment: can you show us a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nZUB9/ try playing with the HTML frame width and you'd see the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This thread is a bit old, but I had the same issue recently and used this to prevent the list items from getting cut:

```
li {
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
}
```

More info on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/)

Hope it helps anyone in the same boat!

Comment: that didn't fix it for me.  on Chrome 57.0

Comment: @ekkis Did you by chance put the rules on the `ul` instead of the `li`s? I did that mistake..

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be linked to margins on `li` elements and `ol`.
From jsfiddle.net/nZUB9 I [reseted your CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) at first and then turn `margin: 6px 0;` into `padding: 6px 0;`
It did the job for me ;)

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: arial, verdana;
}

.task-wrapper {
-moz-column-width: 310px;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-width: 310px;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
column-width: 310px;
column-gap: 10px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

ol.tasks {
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 0;
    display: block;
}

ol.tasks li {
border-bottom: 1px dotted rgba(0, 30, 30, 0.3);
background-color: white;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

ol.tasks li {
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 30, 30, 0.3);
padding: 6px 0;
list-style-type: decimal;
width: 310px;
}
```

Comment: it seems that even with padding it cuts off when you play with the HTML winlet width:
(tested on chrome)
http://jsfiddle.net/nZUB9/1/

Comment: I removed a maximum of code to identify the issue. It seems to work better, except for the last `li` element which disappear when I resized the viewport to its minimal width... not really great.. http://jsfiddle.net/nZUB9/2/

Comment: i wonder what the issue is. it might be a browser bug, no? i wonder if there is a work around. regarding the simplified version - unfortunately my <li> is not simple ;-)

Comment: i saw that ;) as you said, maybe it's due to the early implementation. But i understand you want to give it a try ^^. Did you tried with other elements types (eg: div)?

Comment: btw, maybe you can use something like [jquery.masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) to achieve it. It mimic column structure pretty well